# A claim in Krengel's book on Ergodic Theorems.

Tags: functional-analysis, ergodic-theory

In Krengel's it's argued that the fact that $\exists 0\ne u \in L_\infty$ orthogonal to $(zI-T)L_1$ , where $z$ is a complex number on the unit circle, $|z|=1$, then $T^* u = zu$.

I don't understnad how did they get: $T^* u = zu$?

I mean $(u,(zI-T)v)=0 \forall v \in L^1$ which would entail that $T^* u = \bar{z}u= 1/z u$, since $z\bar{z}=1$.

It's presented on page 317 in the proof of proposition 25.
https://books.google.co.il/books?id=OAUyQph3oVYC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the definition of the adjoint you have for all $v\in L^1$
$$T^*(u)(v)= u(T(v))=u(zv)=zu(v),$$
hence $T^*(u)=zu$.

Comment: why does $T(v)=zv$? thanks.

Comment: I am trying to ping you Jochen, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: $T (v)=zv $ is not necessarily true but $u((zI-T)(v))=0$.

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist: When you ping the author in a comment below his answer, the system removes the author's name because it is guaranteed that he will get a notification by default, so the ping is useless. I had this issue too as a beginner...